# Private Repository Composer json Confused

Tags: github, composer-php, repository, magento2

I need to create a Private Composer Repository - it has 300 zipped extensions. which I want to install on Magento 2 site.

Each zipped extension file inside has its own composer.json file. as some extensions rely on other extensions to be installed aswell in order for them to work.

However when I try to run composer update it is looking for composer.json in the main directory url

Is there any way I can create a simple composer.json to direct it to look for the composer.json of the extensions I want to install inside the different extensions zipped files.

I have spent 2 days looking for tutorial or help on this but its very confusing for me.

tried to get composer to look inside the zipped folders

I just created a new private reposotory and uploaded all the zipped extensions to there - Do I have to do anything futher or is that it?
do I need to convert it to package - very confused

I manage to create the composer.json file

However if I try to run composer update it is giving errors like
- Root composer.json requires extcrea/extension == 1.13.5.0, found extcrea/extension[1.13.5] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.

I tried to change the urls of the extensions inside composer.lock file to the new private repo

then run
composer update --lock

which is suppose to sync to new repository but I get same error again - how do I tell it to look for extensions in the new repository

tried deleting the composer.lock file but getting extension not found error

tried these aswell
composer dump-autoload
composer clear-cache

Or can someone provide a more simple way of being able to do what I want as

Comment: Why not use Satis for this?

Comment: thanks but what does satis do? im confused about the steps needed or order of things to be done - I thought if I create a private repoistory on github and create  "github-oauth": { entry in my auth.json It will allow me to install those extension.

Comment: and allow me to run composer update aswell

Comment: Satis helps you to manage multiple packages while offering a REST API that is compatible with composer as a repository similar to Packagist, the default composer repository. Additionally all repositories that are supported and how they are defined is information available in the manual: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md - you should provide references and configuration examples in your question at least as otherwise it is not really clear what you ask for, so I'd also say the best first comment would be to either signal for *Satis* (service) or perhaps *Artifact* (repository).

Comment: thanks I think Artifact  is more close to what I want I found jfrog but they have limts on number of files you can upload and also size of files also there documenation for windows is scattered all over -

Comment: also can you clarify whats the difference if any between repository and package and what do I need

Comment: @yend84: regarding my earlier comment, the nomenclature is from the referenced document. you can find the reference documentation there about all these, at least to all things Composer.